# change file name in mysql -joomla and store has a unique name in database?

Tags: php, mysql, string, image, joomla

hi friends this is my code for save -> for uploading a image only if the insert is succesfull based on id

but have a problem that the file has moved to the upload folder but has not been updated in database how do update the uploaded image in database and chane the name of uploaded image so that its unique

like mypic.jpg becomes mypic90.jpg after being uploded and then updated to the datbase with the user id. i hope my question helps others like me ?

```
function save() {

        $greeting = JRequest::get ( 'POST' );
        $model = & $this->getModel ( 'greetings' );

        $id = $model->saveGreeting ( $greeting );

        if( !empty($id)){
            $file = JRequest::getVar ( 'greeting_pic', null, 'files', 'array' );

            jimport ( 'joomla.filesystem.file' );
            $filename = JFile::makeSafe ( $file ['name'] );

            //Set up the source and destination of the file
            $src = $file ['tmp_name'];

            //$dest = JPATH_ROOT . BI_IMAGE_BASE . "myfile.jpg<br>";
            $dest = JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . "uploads" . DS . $filename;

            JFile::upload ( $src, $dest );

            // update the field greeting_pic //
            //$result = $model->updateGreetingPic($filename, $id);
        }

        $redirectTo = JRoute::_ ( 'index.php?option=' . JRequest::getVar ( 'option' ) . '&task=display' );
        $this->setRedirect ( $redirectTo, 'Greeting Saved!' );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the uploaded file to the unique id of the greeting, keeping the file extension. Thus you'll avoid conflicts of the filenames:

```
$newFileName = $id . '.' .  strtolower( JFile::getExt( $fileName));
$dest = JPATH_COMPONENT . DS . "uploads" . DS . $newFileName;
$result = $model->updateGreetingPic($newFileName, $id);
```

There will be files like 90.jpg 91.png 92.gif etc.

Comment: i have been wondering about the code can u help for the  updategreting pic code in model and thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the initial question. What's the database schema of the component?

Comment: ok serg i figured it out myself i had been using mysql on phpmyadmin3  thanks for helping

Comment: Hi Justin. Glad to hear you solved it.
Note: under _database schema_ I meant which tables and table fields are involved in the component, and how they are related.